# phonegap XML parser in ajax geting error on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

with including jquery-1.8.3.min.js ajax xml parsing working fine. If i including jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js means getting error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myurl.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access."

I already tried

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.support.cors = true;
      $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://myurl.com",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('ad').each(function(){
                   var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                   alert(url);
                   var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                   var details = $(this).find('content').text();
                   $("#BlogList").append("<div class='blog_listing'>                                                                     <div class='blog_list_title'><a href='"+$.trim(url)+"' title='"+$.trim(title)+"'>"+$.trim(title)+"</a></div><div class='blog_list_detials'><p>"+$.trim(details)+"</p></div></div>");

                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It's not working

Comment: are you using both jquery 1.8.3 and jquery mobile 1.3.2? try with jquery 1.9.1

Comment: @jcesar now i tried with jquery 1.9.1 it's also show same error.

Comment: Do you load index.html from remote server? Error: domain of index.html not same with url you send request. On server, put Access-Control-Allow-Origin = '*' to permiss all domain access

Comment: @Hanh Le i have to tried with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in .htaccess but it's also showing same error. i need to parser the xml feed from Wordpress.

Comment: I not sure, problem from JQM. You should check [allowCrossDomainPages](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)

Answer (score 3):

I cant seem to find the jquery file added in your snapshot given,in case you have added it and still face the problem then I recommend you to try the below methodology and let me know.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin error generally comes up due to the browser web security permissions.
If you are running the ajax request in chrome,then I recommend you to do disable-web-security in chrome and try it.

In case you are using MAC then in terminal type the below code and enter :-

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --user-data-dir=~/chrome-test/ spec/runner.html
```

In case you are using windows go to the command prompt and go into the folder where Chrome.exe is and type

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

Try doing it and run your project in the browser that opens up after running the below code in terminal and let me know if it works.